# Custom navigation with Swiper React and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I am using [Swiper React](https://swiperjs.com/react) to create a carousel.

After following [this issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3855), I am trying to get it working.

I created a custom hook:

```
// useSwiperRef.ts
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const useSwiperRef = () => {
  const [wrapper, setWrapper] = useState(null);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWrapper(ref.current);
  }, []);

  return [wrapper, ref];
};

export default useSwiperRef;
```

And my Carousel:

```
import useSwiperRef from 'useSwiperRef.js';

const Slider = () => {

    const [nextEl, nextElRef] = useSwiperRef();
    const [prevEl, prevElRef] = useSwiperRef();

    return (
        <Container>
            <Swiper
                navigation={{
                    prevEl,
                    nextEl,
                }}
            >
                <SwiperSlide>1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>3</SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
            <Nav ref={prevElRef} />
            <Nav ref={nextElRef} />
        </Container>
    );
};
```

But I get the following typescript error on `prevEl` and `nextEl` inside `navigation {{}}`:

> Type 'MutableRefObject | null' is not assignable to type
> 'HTMLElement | CSSSelector | null | undefined'.   Type
> 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement |
> CSSSelector | null | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject' is missing the following properties from type 'CSSSelector': charAt, charCodeAt, concat, indexOf, and 43
> more.

Anybody an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3855

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation nextEl and prevEl receive HTMLElement or string with CSS selector, so it should be something like this:

```
<Swiper
  navigation={{
   prevEl: '.prev',
   nextEl: '.next',
 }}
>
    <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <div className="prev"></div>
    <div className="next"></div>
</Swiper>
```

In my case I did like this:

```
<div className='slider-wrapper'>
    <Swiper
      navigation={{
       prevEl: '.prev',
       nextEl: '.next',
     }}
    >
        <SwiperSlide>slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    
    </Swiper>
    <div className="prev"></div>
    <div className="next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: off-topic answer